Remove black dot when show display:'none' in view style in react native
I wrote a app with react native
in one my page I used a View with this style
display: IsShow ? "flex" : "none"
when IsShow value is false then display:'none' actived , a black dot(.) replace that View.
how to remove this dot?

I add opacity: IsShow ? 1 : 0 in View style
